# How to calculate Electric and Magnetic Field of TEM waves through a coaxial cable?

Tags: homework-and-exercises, magnetic-fields, electric-fields

So basically if you have a coaxial cable (inner radius a and outer radius b) with a dielectric between the two conductors (with permittivity ϵ and magnetic permeability  µ ) and the monochromatic TEM waves propagating in the +z direction how might I go about solving for the x, y-dependence of the complex electric field and the full electric field at some position z along the line and some time t (using Gauss' law). Additionally how would I solve for the magnetic field using Faraday's law.

Some important additional information. The inner cylinder has equipotential, the electric field outside the surface of the inner cylinder has constant magnitude E0.Solutions of Maxwell's equations in the transmission line corresponding to TEM waves have the form of the real part of the complex wave functions.
E˜(x,y,z,t)=˜E(x,y)e^i(kgz−ωt)

H˜ (x,y,z,t)=H˜(x,y)e^i(kgz−ωt)

It can be shown that the x, y components of the electric field can be found from solving for the fields in the same way one would for a simple 2-D electrostatics problem where one can assume that the charge and current distribution is uniform over an infinitely long coaxial cable.

Comment: Gauss's Law (or rather, Coulomb's law) and Faraday's Law are not sufficient to solve for the fields in a waveguide (coaxial or otherwise) mode, because they neglect the terms in Maxwell's equations by which the electric and magnetic fields are coupled.

Comment: I updated with additional details. You can use Gauss's law and faraday's law assuming a couple things.

Comment: It sounds like you already know what answer you want to hear, so why are you asking the question?

Comment: I dont know how to do it mathematically. Thats why I am asking. What is confusing about that?

Comment: OK, then at least share a reference where you found the claim that "the x, y components of the electric field can be found from solving for the fields in the same way one would for a simple 2-D electrostatics problem", because so far as I know the propagating mode solutions don't have much in common with the static solution. For example the radial dependence in the static case is $1/r$ (as you'd expect from Gauss's Law) but in the propagating mode it's a Bessel function.

Comment: This is a problem given in class and that is simply given to us as a basis for this problem. Not really sure how to reference that. At this point I am unsure what else to say as I have given every single bit of information given to me in the problem. We are asked to solve for electric field, magnetic field, impedance, propagation velocity, momentum density, angular momentum density, time average Poynting flux, and stress tensor in the case of splitting the outer conductor into an upper and lower shell (for the upper shell). I simply wondered if anyone could point to how to start doing all this